# Long running MongoDB query - using connection metrics is it possible to gauge progress?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**Context**

In the process of running a remove script on a MongoDB collection named DeviceLocation2.

Pulling metrics before execution there are 20,192,184 documents older than 2016-06-01 to be deleted.

The remove operation has been running for 42873 sec.

There are a number of metrics displayed as part of the Current Operation connection "conn1120213" all listed below.

**Question**

I am trying to figure out if any of these Current Operations metrics give me an indication of the progress of this job so far ?

Clearly I could run a count on the remaining document but this will take more than 24 hours. Note .explain was used to ensure an index is hit for all operations.

**Operation**

```
remove  {
"DeviceId": {
"$gte": -2147483648
},
"SampleDateTime": {
"$lt": {
  "$date": "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
}
}
{
"desc": "conn1120213",
"threadId": "0x1774ba80",
"connectionId": 1120213,
"opid": 474308850,
"active": true,
"secs_running": 42873,
"microsecs_running": 42873556048,
"op": "remove",
"ns": "DeviceLocation2",
"query": {
"DeviceId": {
  "$gte": -2147483648
},
"SampleDateTime": {
  "$lt": {
    "$date": "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
},
"client": "62.255.27.49:33590",
"numYields": 803758,
"locks": {},
"waitingForLock": false,
"lockStats": {
"Global": {
  "acquireCount": {
    "r": 3408578,
    "w": 3408578
  }
},
"MMAPV1Journal": {
  "acquireCount": {
    "w": 3433949
  },
  "acquireWaitCount": {
    "w": 402551
  },
  "timeAcquiringMicros": {
    "w": 9444549309
  }
},
"Database": {
  "acquireCount": {
    "w": 3408578
  },
  "acquireWaitCount": {
    "w": 88
  },
  "timeAcquiringMicros": {
    "w": 136962266
  }
},
"Collection": {
  "acquireCount": {
    "W": 803758
  },
  "acquireWaitCount": {
    "W": 25285
  },
  "timeAcquiringMicros": {
    "W": 2633178781
  }
},
"oplog": {
  "acquireCount": {
    "w": 2604820
  },
  "acquireWaitCount": {
    "w": 66293
  },
  "timeAcquiringMicros": {
    "w": 15788967730
  }
}
}
}
```

Thank you for any help.
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer appears to be that none of the above metrics indicate progress. Unfortunately `MongoDB` has no built-in way of tracking query / operation progress - other than on index builds.

That leaves me with:

- FIND / COUNT the data being deleted to see how many documents are still being returned, or haven't been deleted yet. As indicated before this is very time consuming.
- FIND predefined single documents by id at specific date point.  In hindsight knowing the ID of the first document per day over the REMOVE date range would have allowed me to quickly query for progress.
- Mongo reports total documents per collection. By knowing the total to be deleted too and approx ingress during the remove operation period this can offer indicative progress.

Thanks
Scott